# Last element of this group of node xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

XML data :

```
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_NAV3>
        <IMMUTABLE_ID>5786
        </IMMUTABLE_ID>
        <INSTRUCTION_LIST>
            <INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
                <NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT>
                        <DESCRIPTION>
                            <P>descrzione breve di una storia</P>
                        </DESCRIPTION>
                    </NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT>
            </INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
        </INSTRUCTION_LIST>
    </NTC_NAV3>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_NAV3>
        <IMMUTABLE_ID>5787
        </IMMUTABLE_ID>
        <INSTRUCTION_LIST>
            <INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
                <NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT>
                        <DESCRIPTION>
                            <P>descriviamo in questo capitolo qualcosa</P>
                        </DESCRIPTION>
                    </NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT>
            </INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
        </INSTRUCTION_LIST>
    </NTC_NAV3>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>

XSL:   

    <xsl:for-each select="SECTION_CONTENT_LIST">
    <xsl:for-each select="SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM">
        <xsl:sort select="NTC_NAV3/IMMUTABLE_ID" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="NTC_NAV3">
            <div style="text-align:left; border-top:2px solid black;">
            <span style="line-height:normal; text-align:center; ">
            <xsl:value-of select=".//NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT/DESCRIPTION"/>
            </span>
            </div>                          
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>    


In output I would only the output  :
descriviamo in questo capitolo qualcosa
this is the last description orderd by immutable_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
<xsl:for-each select="SECTION_CONTENT_LIST">
    <xsl:for-each select="SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM">
    <xsl:sort select="NTC_NAV3/IMMUTABLE_ID" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="NTC_NAV3[last()]">
            <div style="text-align:left; border-top:2px solid black;">
            <span style="line-height:normal; text-align:center; ">
            <xsl:value-of select=".//NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT/DESCRIPTION"/>
            </span>
            </div>                          
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

assuming you only want to process the last `NTC_NAV3` element.

If that does not help then consider to show a sample of the XML input and the corresponding HTML output you want to create with XSLT.

Comment: i would only the last element of this node group.

Comment: this return a set of DESCRIPTION, i would only the last

Comment: Consider to edit your question and to provide a sample of the XML you have.

Comment: XML data :               
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_NAV3>
            <IMMUTABLE_ID>5786
            </IMMUTABLE_ID>
            <INSTRUCTION_LIST>
                <INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
                    <NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT>
                            <DESCRIPTION>
                                <P>descrzione breve di una storia</P>
                            </DESCRIPTION>
                        </NTC_NAV3INSTRUCT>
                </INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
            </INSTRUCTION_LIST>
        </NTC_NAV3>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>

Comment: solution : <xsl:if test="position() = last()">